# Sequence contains no elements XAML ContentPage

Tags: xamarin.forms

In line 1, my axml file reports the error Sequence contains no elements ...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:my_namespace"
             x:Class="my_class_name"
             Title="Login"
             NavigationPage.HasNavigationBar="false">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center">
            <ContentView Padding="0,40,0,40" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                <Image Source="xamarin_logo.png" VerticalOptions="Center" HeightRequest="64" />
            </ContentView>
        </StackLayout>
        <StackLayout Spacing="10" Padding="20" VerticalOptions="Center">
            <Entry x:Name="companyNameEntry" Placeholder="Nome Società" Text="TERMINALINI" />
            <Entry x:Name="usernameEntry" Placeholder="ID Utente" Text="manager" />
            <Entry x:Name="passwordEntry" Placeholder="Password" IsPassword="true" Text="XXX" />
            <Button Text="Login" TextColor="White" BackgroundColor="#77D065" Clicked="OnLoginButtonClicked" />
            <Label x:Name="messageLabel" />
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

I tried what the error meant but I do not understand it ... what did I do wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A ContentPage's Content property can only contain a single child.  You have two StackLayouts as direct children of Content.  They need to be enclosed in a single layout container.